# "combined" printer and scanner for linux

Tags: linux, scanner

Can anyone recommend a combined scanner and printer (so that the photocopying and the faxing capabiities can be used autonomously, even when the computer is off) which works reasonably well with linux?

Is there a list of such scanners online? SANE's list does not contain a category of "combined" printing+scanning device.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HP devices are great for that. hplip is open-source and included by default in quite a few Linux distros, so that HP multifunction printers are recognized automatically. They're also good quality. The HP PSC series works very well on Linux.